# Why can I not convert my integer to a double?

Tags: java, arrays, average

I am trying to work out the average of the array but I cannot convert the int into a double? why is this happening?

```
private void AvgOfArray(){

            myWindow.clearOut();
            int total = 0;
            int[] a = new int[4];
            int i = 0;
            double avg = 0.0;
            while (i < a.length) {
                a[i] = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 10);
                myWindow.writeOutLine(a[i]);
                total += a[i];
                i++;
            }
            avg = (Double) i;
            myWindow.writeOutLine(total/Double.parseDouble(i));


        }
```

Comment: `Double.parseDouble(i)` does not take an `int`. If you make `total` a `double`, you wouldn't have to do casting at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to calculate the average is something like,

```
double avg = total / (double) i;
myWindow.writeOutLine(avg);
```

Boxing an `int` to a `Double` doesn't make much sense, especially to then try and parse it.